# postgresql with timescale upgrade

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, pg-upgrade

I have an installation of Postgresql 9.6.11 with shared library of Timescale 1.1.1 installed. I am trying to upgrade both of them, using in-place upgrade for Timescale and `pg_upgrade` for Postgres, i.e Postgresql to 11.5 and Timescale to 1.4. Which should I upgrade first? I was successfully able to upgrade Timescale first and then I tried to proceed with pg_upgrade, but I ran into error
`pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 1012; 1259 24224 TABLE cache_inval_extension`
I am wondering if I should have installed Postgresql 11.5 with Timescale 1.1.1. And then use pg_upgrade and then in-place for timescale.

Comment: It should not matter which way you do it. I'd ask TimescaleDB for help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe you were right on both statement. Unfortunately only first was completely in my control. I tried either way and both worked. The trick was to pass  -O "-c timescaledb.restoring='on'" to pg_upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I learned after trying that you can do it either way. You just need to let timescale know that upgrade is in progress using the command `-O "-c timescaledb.restoring='on'"` when running pg_upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can find solution [here](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/upgrades/upgrade-pg/);

Shortly, **upgrade** your postgres version which supports your current timescale version. After that upgrade your timecale to highest supported version with your new postgresql.

If this final version is not your desired version so repeat above.

Comment: I know this is an old question but many people is asking this method even today...